# Unmanaged package test class Test records required fields?

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package

I'm building an unmanaged package in a developer instance.
I have a custom object  which has master-detail relationship with Opportunity.

When I write the test methods for my apex classes,  I have to create test records of Opportunity and Account.

What will happen if the target instances have required custom fields on Account or Opportunity?

In my test class, do I have to use schema class to find the required fields first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of what you're trying to do, at minimum you could try performing the insert, then checking the [`DmlException`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm#dml_email_exception_methods) methods to determine which fields failed, via `getDmlFields()`, in which case, you might try iterating over the list, determining the data type via describe calls, setting any values on fields the system complains about (or just those where `getDmlType` equals `StatusCode.REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING`), then making a second attempt to save.

Of course, because we can also have validation rules, required lookup filters, addError messages, and so on, you might end up with a very complex class structure, and *not all validations can be evaluated with absolute certainty in Apex Code*. If the second pass fails, you should probably report the error so it can be fixed manually somehow (unless, of course, this breaks your installation, in which case you may want to just silently abort early, and hope there's enough code coverage).

However, if the org is already pretty heavy on utilization, you might find that a double-save mechanism might cause test timeouts or other governor limits to be hit, so describing beforehand *might* be worthwhile, but the inverse is also true-- your test may well fail if it has to describe hundreds of fields before it can even build a single record. You'll have to figure out which of the two is more efficient in your case, because it will vary from org to org; it might even be worth the trouble to build a hybrid based on the number of fields an org has for those objects.

Finally, you might also just make a requirement that a static resource must be uploaded beforehand, so you can simply use [`Test.loadData`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_loadData); this means that the test can be dynamically populated from static resources, allowing required fields and other nuances to be deployed before your package is.